# tSugarCRMOutput to tFileInputExcel in Talend

Tags: salesforce, sugarcrm, talend

I have migrated data from SaleForce to SugarCRM using `tSalesForceInput` at SalesForce site &  `tSugarCRMOutput` at SugarCRM site & and mapped them using `tMap`. I have successfully migrated this data. Now I want to save this data into Excel from `tSugarCRMOutput` to          `tFileInputExcel` in same job after completion of `tSalesForceInput` to `tSugarCRMOutput`.
How can I do this? Suggest me if any alternate way to do this?

**Solved**

Yeahh I have done this using trigger. For that I have linked to the tSugarCRMInput using trigger onComponentOk from tSugarCRMOutput and used tFileOutputExcel after tSugarCRMInput to save this data into Excel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeahh I have done this using trigger. For that I have linked to the tSugarCRMInput using trigger onComponentOk from tSugarCRMOutput and used tFileOutputExcel after tSugarCRMInput to save this data into Excel